# Lower bound of the degree of an ample rational curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Fano manifold of Picard number one with non-nef tangent bundle. Is there any lower bound of the anti-canonical degree of an ample rational curve ?

Comment: What is an ample curve?

Comment: Based on past MO posts, I suspect that an "ample curve" means a "very free curve."  I also suspect that what the OP wants is actually an *upper bound* on the least anticanonical degree of a very free curve.  This does follow, for all Fano manifolds, from the work of Koll\'ar -- Miyaoka -- Mori, and even earlier results by Campana and Nadel for Picard rank one (I believe all of these bounds are in the textbook by Debarre)  Perhaps the OP is asking if there is any improvement on those bounds under the additional hypothesis that the tangent bundle is not nef.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong.  Maybe the OP is asking about a lower bound.  I think we have a lower bound due to Mukai . . .

Comment: @abx By ample curve I meant very free curve.

Comment: @ Jason Starr Yes. I am asking for the lower bound. Could you please let me know the reference you are talking about ?

Comment: There is an obvious lower bound: if $C\cong \mathbb{P}^1$ is very free, we have $T_{X|C}=\sum \mathscr{O}(a_i)$ with $a_i\geq 1$ and $a_1\geq 2$ (since $T_{X|C}\supset T_C$),  hence $(-K_X\cdot C)\geq \dim X+1$.